# Form with only a button

Tags: php, html

I have a html project with PHP and I want to be able to have a button that when I click on him, a POST request to be executed. The problem is that I want to be able to also send some parameters through the request but I don't want to have input fields.

Comment: You can add [hidden input fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden). They will be sent when you submit the form, just like any other input field, but won't be rendered in the view.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) In your case: what info do you want exactly and how/where is it used?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid to say that it is impossible when you only use HTML each element of HTML have their usage and you can not send parameters like what you described the only thing you can send by a button is its name and value solutions to this situation is using hidden input type or sending these parameters by AJAX or socket as JSON for example. any sub-element of form tag in HTML will be received to the server as post global array and they generate by input fields inside the form so you can not have another input in the server if you don't create it in HTML unless you don't use HTML for requesting to the server I mean it's possible but not with HTML